# How to fix catkin_make error for px-ros-pkg?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use the ROS interface for the PX4flow optical flow board. I git cloned px-ros-pkg into my catkin workspace src subdirectory. This is what i get when i catkin_make:-

```
 Base path: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/aman/new_catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.74
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 3 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - px_comm
-- ~~  - mavlink_serial_client
-- ~~  - px4flow
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'px_comm'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(px-ros-pkg/px_comm)
-- px_comm: 3 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'mavlink_serial_client'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(px-ros-pkg/drivers/mavlink_serial_client)
CMake Error at /home/aman/new_catkin_ws/devel/share/px_comm/cmake/px_commConfig.cmake:130 (message):
  Project 'mavlink_serial_client' tried to find library 'px_comm_dds'.  The
  library is neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile
  project 'px_comm'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory
  containing its code is included?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package)
  px-ros-pkg/drivers/mavlink_serial_client/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Why is this happening and what is the fix? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89901/how-to-fix-catkin_make-error-for-px-ros-pkg?/) by [AmanJotwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4881/amanjotwani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like px_comm exports the library in its catkin_package() command but it does not pass the if statement
`if(DEFINED ENV{NDDSHOME})` in its CMakeLists.txt, so it does not build the library

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AmanJotwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4881/amanjotwani/) on 2013-10-12**:
I just checked that and turns out it does pass the above statement. Here's the line -

if(DEFINED ENV{NDDSHOME})
set(NDDSHOME $ENV{NDDSHOME})

Thanks though.

**Comment by [AmanJotwani](https://answers.ros.org/users/4881/amanjotwani/) on 2013-11-06**:
Instead of catkin, i did rosbuild, and it worked out fine. But i am still interested to know where i was going wrong with the catkin_make. :-)